# handling subprocess file output

Tags: django, ffmpeg, django-views, subprocess

I am working on a project in which at some point user uploads a video and in backend i have to generate thumbnail for that video. I preferred ffmpeg for this purpose and the system is in django environment.
This is my view function

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            filename = str(request.FILES['docfile'].name)
            newdoc.save()
            op = subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i',"media/private/"+up, '-ss', '00:00:03.000', '-vframes', '1', 'abc.jpg']) // Generates thumbnail
            newdoc.thumbnail = op
            newdoc.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
```

The Document has the thumbnail field. I know that subprocess.call() returns returncode not any object so using op variable is useless. So my query is how do i save generated thumbnail in model.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) of `FieldFile` you could open the file from the path you saved it to and wrap it into a `File` object.

Another consideration would be to move away from calling subprocesses and instead using a python library. There are also python bindings for ffmpeg e.g. [ffmpeg-python](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/).